# What is difference b/w PRLock and PRRWLock

Tags: c++, nspr

What is the difference b/w **`PRLock`** and **`PRRWLock`**
provided by nspr library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about the library but the names suggest that one is a standard lock and the other is a reader/writer lock. The first always gives exclusive access, and the second allows multiple concurrent reads but exclusive writes. For example, pthreads api has pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock and pthread_rwlock_rdlock/pthread_rwlock_wrlock methods.

Comment: +1; looking at the source they use `pthread_rwlock_rdlock/pthread_rwlock_wrlock` to implement it if PThreads are available.

Answer (score 0):

[PRLock is a simple mutex](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/nspr/reference/html/prlock.html). PRRWLock is an ([unfortunately](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.nspr/browse_thread/thread/58557e6faff4728c) [undocumented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87200)) [reader-writer lock](http://mxr.mozilla.org/nspr/source/nsprpub/pr/src/threads/prrwlock.c#70).

The only source of documentation I can find on PRRWLock is contained within [`prrwlock.h`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/nspr/source/nsprpub/pr/include/prrwlock.h), and includes the methods one would expect for a reader-writer lock implementation:

- Create and Destroy
- Acquire Reader-lock
- Acquire Writer-lock
- Release the lock

An example of its usage is contained in [`rwlocktest.c`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/nspr/source/nsprpub/pr/tests/rwlocktest.c). The *rank* of the lock is used for deadlock detection and is asserted in debug builds to ensure that a thread only acquires a lock of rank equal or greater to all currently held locks.